# Finding curves whose tangents intersect with the x-axis at $(\frac{x}{2},0)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, plane-curves

I have to find the family of curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with this property:

The tangent in an arbitrary point on the curve does intersect with the x-axis in $(\frac{x}{2}, 0)$.

I think I have to make a differential equation first, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P=(\bar x,f(\bar x))$ be a point of the curve. The tangent at this point has equation:
$$
y-f(\bar x)=f'(\bar x)(x-\bar x)
$$

We want that the point $(\bar x/2,0)$ is on this line, so we have:

$$
-f(\bar x)=f'(\bar x)(\frac{\bar x}{2}-\bar x)
$$

since this have to be true for all $\bar x$ we have the equation:

$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{2}f'(x)
$$
that has simple solution.

Comment: How did you get your third equation from your second?

Comment: we have: $-f(\bar x)=-\frac{\bar x}{2}f'(\bar x)$, that **must be true for all $\bar x \in \mathbb{R}$**, so we can simply write $x$ for $\bar x$.

Comment: The final solution is $f(x)=cx^2$.

Comment: Yes it is. The diff. equation is separable and easily solved.